# How to programmatically get touch coordinates to the screen in Android?

Tags: android, position, touch, coordinates, screen

How to programmatically get touch coordinates to the screen in Android, regardless of open applications or games? The display of these coordinates can be turned on in the Developer options menu. [Example of required coordinates.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9TCm.png) But how to get access to them, which class is responsible for this? Maybe there is some library or some way to find it?
I tried to use Accessibility service, but it doesn't have this data.

Comment: You can't really do it due to privacy/security reasons.

Comment: If this is a private app, you can do it by rooting the device.  But in a normal app there's no way to do this.  ANd even if an accessibility service could, Google won't let you on the playstore with that permission if you aren't an actual accessibility service.